# What is wrong with my approach to solving $x^{\log25} + 25^{\log x} = 10\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms, roots

Found this equation on the web: $$x^{\log25} + 25^{\log x} = 10$$
The person solved by substitution and got $x = \sqrt{10}$ which satisfies the equation.

I tried different ways after following the man's substitution method. I tried this:
$$\log\left(x^{\log25}\right) + \log\left(25^{\log x}\right) = \log 10$$

Using laws of logs:
$$\begin{align}
\log25 \cdot \log x + \log x\cdot\log 25 &= \log 10\\ 
1.3979 \log x + \log x (1.3979) &= 1\\
2.7958 \log x &= 1\\
\log x &= 0.357\\
x &= 10^{0.3576} \approx 2.278
\end{align}$$
This is wrong, however.

Why aren't the laws of logs holding? I'm missing something.

Sorry for asking what I'm sure is a ignorant question. I like math but am hardly an expert.

Comment: $\log_b(a+c)\ne\log_ba+\log_bc$

Comment: Thank you, Aiden.  I'm sorry but I don't see where this applies to what I did.  Could you elaborate a bit. Thank you again. Not a math wizard.

Comment: @Frederick Please see the answer I've just posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your approach is your first step: taking the log of both sides.
When you take the log of both sides, you get
$$\log(x^{\log25}+25^{\log x})=\log10$$
This is valid. However, you then somehow transform this equation into what you have written in your question:
$$\log(x^{\log25})+\log(25^{\log x})=\log10$$
This is now invalid, because of the fact that $\log_b(a+c)\ne\log_ba+\log_bc$. That is to say, you can't simply split a sum inside a logarithm like what you did.

Comment: Aiden, thank you very much. Your explanation helped me greatly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Frederick If you feel that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please click the green check mark next to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

Here is a solution with which you can compare:

\begin{align*}
x^{\log(25)} + 25^{\log(x)} = 10 & \Longleftrightarrow 10^{\log(x^{\log(25)})} + 10^{\log(25^{\log(x)})} = 10\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2\times 10^{\log(25)\log(x)} = 10\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 10^{\log(25)\log(x)} = 5\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \log(25)\log(x) = \log(5)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \log(x) = \frac{\log(5)}{\log(25)}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \log(x) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Si. Muchas Gracias por la Ayuda.  Buena Suerte con Su Ph.D.Candidatura.

Comment: @Frederick Muchas gracias ! :D